# How to assign variable to the result of a method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, return-value

I'm new to the concept of methods in C#, and I am trying to wrap my head around solving this problem that uses methods to calculate compound interest. I am having a couple problems with the code itself, but the main concept I am struggling with is how to return the variable "double finalAmount" through the use of my methods CalculateCompoundInterest (both variations). Here is my code so far:

```
using System;

namespace CompoundInterestCalculator
{
    public class CompoundCalculator
    {
        const int EXIT = 0;
        const int CALCULATE_DAILY = 1;
        const int CALCULATE_QUARTERLY = 2;
        const int CALCULATE_VARIABLE = 3;
        const int NUM_OPTIONS = 3;

        public static void Main()
        {
            int menuOption;
            WelcomeMessage();
            do
            {
                DisplayMenu();
                menuOption = ReadOption();

                if (menuOption != EXIT)
                {
                    double finalAmount = CalculateInterest(menuOption);
                    OutputResult(finalAmount);
                }
            } while (menuOption != EXIT);

            ExitProgram();
        } // end Main

        // Fill in the appropriate modifier and return type (_ _) in the method declaration
        public static void WelcomeMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tCompound Interest Calculator\n");
        } // end WelcomeMessage

        // Fill in the appropriate modifier and return type (_ _) in the method declaration
        public static void  ExitProgram()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nPress enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        } // end ExitProgram

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            string menu = "\n\n1) Calculate final amount after interest     (compounded daily)"
                        + "\n2) Calculate final amount after interest (compounded quarterly)"
                        + "\n3) Calculate final amount after interest (define number of times compounded yearly)"
                        + "\n\nEnter your option(1-3 or 0 to exit): ";

            Console.Write(menu);
        } // end DisplayMenu

        public static void OutputResult(double finalAmount)
        {
            // Display the message "The final amount of money plus interest is: $(amount)"
            // The amount should display as currency, with two decimal places, e.g. $10,000.00

            Console.WriteLine("The final amount of money plus interest is: ${0.2}", finalAmount);
        } // end OutputResult

        static int ReadOption()
        {
            string choice;
            int option;
            bool okayChoice;

            do
            {
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                okayChoice = int.TryParse(choice, out option);
                if (!okayChoice || option < 0 || option > NUM_OPTIONS)
                {
                    okayChoice = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct option.\n\n Please try again");
                    DisplayMenu();
                }
            } while (!okayChoice);

            return option;
        } // end ReadOption

        public static double CalculateInterest(int menuOption)
        {
            // (For this exercise, we will assume the user is inputting correct input.)
            double principal;
            double interestRate;
            int numYears;
            double finalAmount;

            Console.Write("Enter the principal amount: ");
            principal = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the interest rate: ");
            interestRate = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the number of years that interest is accumulated for: ");
            numYears = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (menuOption == CALCULATE_DAILY || menuOption == CALCULATE_QUARTERLY)
            {
                if (menuOption == CALCULATE_DAILY)
                {
                    // Call the appropriate CalculateCompoundInterest method
                    CalculateCompoundInterest( principal,  interestRate,  numYears);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Call the appropriate CalculateCompoundInterest method
                    CalculateCompoundInterest( principal,  interestRate,  numYears,  4);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the number of times the interest is compounded yearly: ");
                int numTimesCompounded = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                // Call the appropriate CalculateCompoundInterest method
                CalculateCompoundInterest( principal,  interestRate,  numYears,  numTimesCompounded);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            // return the amount calculated by the compound interest method

            return finalAmount;

        } // End CalculateInterest

        // Declare and implement the method CalculateCompoundInterest whose parameters are the principal, interest rate, and number of years (in that order)- make sure it is public!
        // For the declaration select an appropriate modifier, return type, and types for the parameters
        // This version assumes the interest is compounded daily (365 times a year)
        // For both methods, you should assume the interest rate is input already in decimal form (i.e. 0.02 rather than 2 for a 2% rate)

        public static double CalculateCompoundInterest(double principal, double interestRate, int numYears )
        {

            double compoundInterest;

            compoundInterest = principal * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / numYears, 1);

            return compoundInterest;
        }

        // Declare and implement the method CalculateCompoundInterest whose parameters are the principal, interest rate, number of years, and number of times compounded yearly - make sure it is public!
        // For the declaration  select an appropriate modifier, return type, and types for the parameters
        // This version allows the number of times compounded yearly to be specified.

        public static double CalculateCompoundInterest(double principal, double interestRate, int numYears, int numTimesCompounded)
        {
            double compoundInterest;

            compoundInterest = principal * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / numYears, numTimesCompounded);

            return compoundInterest;

        }
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

Basically I am trying to figure out how to obtain results from methods, and how to use them in other methods (e.g. for value/parameter arithmetic). Feel free to let me know if you think there is something else that is wrong with the purpose of the program (to calculate compound interest). Also let me know if this is inappropriate for Stack Overflow, I am new to the website. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not understanding the issue you're having? You seem to have got the handle of returning values in `CalculateCompoundInterest`. Can you explain what isn't working for you?

Comment: did u received any error or exception? so provide us

Comment: Do `double returnedValue = CalculateCompoundInterest(2.0D, 2.0D, 2);` ? This will store the returned value in the new variable 'returnedValue'

Comment: Can you please edit your post, and add only relevant and necessary code only?

Comment: A `void` method doesn´t *return* anything. But I don´t get why you even *want* your main-method to return anything. the `finalOutput` should be already be printed by `OutputResult`, shouldn´t it? So from which method you need a result and where do you want to use it? Doesn´t your code does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Your program seems to already include the concepts you are asking about. You are already returning results from methods using `return` statements and you are already saving returned values and using them (eg `double finalAmount = CalculateInterest(menuOption); OutputResult(finalAmount);`). It looks like you might need to just look over what you've got and make sure you understand it all, both where you are having a problem (in case you made a mistake you can recognise) and where your code is working (to make sure you understand why it is working).

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, let me try to clarify. When I try to compile my code, I get an error stating that on line 129 where I have "return finalAmount", it says that "Use of an unassigned local variable 'finalAmount'".

My understanding is that I haven't properly assigned the result from "CalculateCompoundInterest" to the variable "finalAmount". Basically I am having trouble figuring out how to assign a value to finalAmount, that comes from an arithmetic answer to the CalculateCompoundInterest method. 

Unless this is an incorrect interpretation? I hope this helps

Comment: if you hae to get rid from error `Use of Unassigned local variable` make changes like `double finalAmount = 0.0M;`

Comment: To the guys voting to close "unclear what you're asking": why? It's perfectly obvious that LawfulNeutral needs to learn about return values.

Answer (score 0):

I 'think' this is what you are looking for

```
var interest = CalculateCompoundInterest( principal,  interestRate,  numYears,  4);
```

**edit**

Additionally you may want to refactor the following 2 methods into 1 method. Hint - optional parameters

```
    public static double CalculateCompoundInterest(double principal, double interestRate, int numYears )
    {

        double compoundInterest;

        compoundInterest = principal * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / numYears, 1);

        return compoundInterest;
    }

    public static double CalculateCompoundInterest(double principal, double interestRate, int numYears, int numTimesCompounded)
    {
        double compoundInterest;

        compoundInterest = principal * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / numYears, numTimesCompounded);

        return compoundInterest;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't think I've explained the problem properly. When I try to compile I get an error stating that on line 129 where I have "return finalAmount", it says that "Use of an unassigned local variable 'finalAmount'". I think the problem is I haven't made finalAmount be determined by the result of the CalculateCompoundInterest method, but I'm not too sure.

Also what do you mean by refactoring the two methods into one? Sorry but I haven't heard the term 'refactoring' used in C before.

Comment: Yes the error you are getting is correct as you haven't ASSIGNED a value to it. You are calling CalculateCompoundInterest but doing nothing with the result. Maybe ASSIGNING what is returned to finalAmount will work.



Refactoring is a general term used in software engineering. Google is your friend.



I'm more puzzled as to why you are having an issue here, you can obviously assign variables, create methods, return values etc but not be able to see the problem...interview/assignment question perhaps?

Comment: Sorry yeah, from reading the code comments then yeah assignment. My advise would be to go though and understand each line. You are calling a method CalculateCompoundInterest. which returns a VALUE. Now that returned value is going nowhere just just returned and lost. Maybe if there was some way to hold onto that value